# Map a keyboard key to act as my left mouse click

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

So my left mouse click its a bit broken.
Then i had an idea to make a python script to map my mouse button to the space key on my keyboard.
I just managed to implement the click but not the hold, and it is still a bit janky so i wanted help with that.

here's my script so far:

```
    import time
    import keyboard
    import pyautogui
    import win32api
    import win32con
    
    
    def LeftClick(x, y):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
    
    
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            print("Left mouse button pressed")
            MousePos = pyautogui.position()
            LeftClick(MousePos.x, MousePos.y)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: if i hold the space button it does not identify that im holding the click button it just sends a bunch of click events